# How to Remove HTML tags from Long Description in Maximo Anywhere app?

Tags: javascript, xml, textarea, maximo, maximo-anywhere

The Long Description is showing unwanted HTML tags in the text. Can anyone suggest an exact way to display the Long description without HTML tags in the Work Execution application of Maximo Anywhere.  I have searched on the internet but couldn't find a perfect solution.

I also tried to remove HTML tags from JavaScript , still < > & symbols are displaying as '**& lt;**' '**& gt;**' '**& amp;**' ....

Comment: Can you post some code snippets of what you have tried and the error/output which you are getting as a result of it.